# Complex Differential Equation: $f'(z)=bf(z) \iff f(z)=ae^{bz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> > Let $f\colon G\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on the domain $G\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and $b\in\mathbb{C}$. Show that the two following statements are equivalent:
> >     1) $f(z)=ae^{bz}$ on $G$ with a constant $a\in\mathbb{C}$ 2) $f'(z)=bf(z)$ on $G$

1) $\Rightarrow$ 2):

My idea is to use
$$
z=x+iy \qquad a=w+iq \qquad b=m+in
$$

what gives
$$
f(z)=(w+iq)\cdot\exp((mx-ny)+(my+nx)\cdot i)
$$

Maybe now one can use $f'(z)=f_x(z)$? Is that a good idea or is it useless to calculate this partial derivation?

2) $\Rightarrow$ 1):

no idea yet

Comment: Do you know how to do it in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Hm, in $\mathbb{R}$ I would simply try to calculate the derivation...

Comment: Regarding 1), do you know that $f'(z) = bae^{bz}$?

Comment: This would have been my result, but I cannot see how one gets that.

Comment: Do you know that given an holomorphic function $g=u+iv$, then $g'=u_x+iv_x$?

Comment: @math12 What have you studied in complex analysis so far? It's unusual to have to deal with complex differential equations before knowing the derivative of $e^{bz}$.

Comment: I know that a holomorphic function fullfills the Cauchy-Riemann-DE and that $f'(z)=f_x(z)$. But I do not see how to write $f(z)$ in the form $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ for $z=x+iy$.

Comment: Is it $u(x,y)=\exp(mx-ny)(w\cos(my+nx)-q\sin(my-nx))$ and $v(x,y)=\exp(mx-ny)(q\cos(my+nx)+w\sin(my-nx))$ for $z=x+iy, a=w+iq, b=m+in$?

Comment: @math12 To write $f=u+iv$ just let $u:=\Re f$ and $v:=\Im f$. You can do it in general, no need to particularlize for this partcial function $f$.

Comment: Yes but one has to calculate u and v explicitly, right? I did in my last comment.

Comment: @math12 I think more context is in order for you to get proper help. Answer Ayman's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438043/complex-differential-equation-fz-bfz-iff-fz-aebz#comment938438_438043) above.

Comment: I simply do not know how to find $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ here. :-)

Comment: Let $z = x + iy$ and use Euler's formula to get: $e^{bz} = e^{bx + iby} = e^{bx}(\cos by + i \sin by)$. Hence, $u(x, y) = e^{bx} \cos by$, $v(x, y) = e^{bx} \sin by$.

Comment: I would say $u(x,y)=ae^{bx}\cos(by)$ and $v(x,y)=ae^{bx}\sin(by)$ and therefore $u_x(x,y)=abe^{bx}\cos(by)$ and $v_x(x,y)=abe^{bx}\sin(by)$. Then $f'(z)=f_x(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)=abe^{bx}(\cos(by)+i\sin(by))=abe^{bz}=bf(z)$.

Comment: Sorry, one more question! You defined $u(x,y)=e^{bx}\cos by$ and $v(x,y)=e^{bx}\sin by$. But how can that be? u and v have to have real images, I think?

Comment: Does the definition of "domain" include its connectedness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1 \Rightarrow 2$: If $f(z) = a e^{bz}$, then $f'(z) = bae^{bz} = bf(z)$.

---

$2 \Rightarrow 1$: Suppose $f'(z) = bf(z)$ and consider $g(z) = e^{-bz}f(z)$. We have:
$$
g'(z) = -be^{-bz}f(z) + e^{-bz}f'(z) = 0
$$

Hence $g$ is constant. We have $g(0) = f(0)$, so let $a = f(0)$. It follows that $g(z) = e^{-bz}f(z) = a$. Thus, $f(z) = ae^{bz}$.

Comment: I understand this proof. But: I would never had come to this proof... how can one have such ideas? I never have ;(

Comment: The trick of considering $e^{-bz}f(z)$ is pretty common in complex analysis. Keep practicing and such tricks will become part of your toolbox. :)

Comment: The trick of considering $e^{-bz}f(z)$ is also common in differential equations.  See "integrating factor".